# How can I center my icon horizontally and vertically?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am trying something like fontawesome and want to center the icon:

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
```

without using a special class todo this with , how can I manage with css? I tried text-align , center etc?

Comment: Wait, without a class? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [can use flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), it can easily solved by `align-items` and `justify-content`. `border` is added just to show the side of the div.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px black dotted; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 50px;">
        <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```